# Unmount the screen(Page) while switching between menus of Drawer Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

In my application i am having a drawer menu with list of menus in it.

For example The drawer menu has 
1. Home
2. Screen A
3. Screen B.

i have overridden the Drawer menu component and on click of the menu item i am calling **NavigationActions.navigate("Route Name")** to open the Drawer screen.

when ever i click the menu item i want to load the recent data from the server through web api but **ComponentWillMoun**t and **Constructor** of the screen is called only for the First time Click and it is not unmounting the component when i switch to other menu.

Is it possible to unmount the screen when user click a new menu item Or to render the fresh component without old state whenever user click the menu from the drawer.?